# How to calculate median of multiple square matrices returning results in a new square one

Tags: r, matrix, median

I have four square matrices and I would like to obtain one square matrix which contains the median value calculated on the values reported in the other matrices.

So for example reporting just the first cell of each matrix:

|  | New York |
| --- | --- |
| Chicago | 3 |

|  | New York |
| --- | --- |
| Chicago | 4 |

|  | New York |
| --- | --- |
| Chicago | 5 |

|  | New York |
| --- | --- |
| Chicago | 12 |

I would like to have an outcome like this:

|  | New York |
| --- | --- |
| Chicago | 4,5 |

Comment: is that a comma or decimal point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have four 2 x 2 matrices called `m1`, `m2`, `m3` and `m4`. Then you can do:

```r
apply(abind::abind(m1, m2, m3, m4, along = 3), 1:2, median)
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]  3.5  5.0
#> [2,]  5.0  3.5
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

**Data used in example**

```r
set.seed(1)

m1 <- matrix(sample(10, 4), 2)
m2 <- matrix(sample(10, 4), 2)
m3 <- matrix(sample(10, 4), 2)
m4 <- matrix(sample(10, 4), 2)
```